# Django - No file write in tmp - invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)

Tags: django, apache, centos7

I put in prod my django site in centos7 server.

I had some recent problem to upload file in tmp directory (it didn't work) so i specify a tmp directory (see the last lines of the `settings.py`).

But i still block on a problem of write file in this directory...

On my dev computer, during the upload the `tmp file` is creating during the uplaod of the web browser (normal indeed). But here, nothinfg is write during the upload on the web browser and i have this error.

## error

```
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:07.440646 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 507] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.692254 2018] [core:notice] [pid 956] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.692948 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 956] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.702639 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 956] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.703223 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 956] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.706726 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 956] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:10.706750 2018] [core:notice] [pid 956] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:14.654917 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 957] invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:14.822955 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 957] [remote 193.49.166.23:37722] invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)
[Thu Oct 11 14:35:14.826607 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 957] [remote 193.49.166.23:37722] Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /importData/upload
```

I think that error occur because the tmp files are not be writted...

## settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for MYSITE project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""
from kombu import Queue
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
with open('/etc/mysecretkeys.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['SERVERIP']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

##### many others APPS ############""

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    "progressbarupload.uploadhandler.ProgressBarUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler",
    "django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler",
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MYSITE.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'MYSITE.context_processors.context'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MYSITE.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'THENAME',
        'USER': 'THEUSER',
        'PASSWORD': 'THEPASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LOGIN_URL = '/users/connexion'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-FR'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True


#########################
#
#       MISCELLANEOUS
#
#########################

# many things

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "tmp")

if not os.path.exists(FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR):
    os.makedirs(FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR, mode=0o644)
```

I am very gracefull if someone can help me, the prod env in centos7 is very weird for a newbie centos wizard.

### EDIT 1 - Permission TMP folder

```
[ME@web01 PATHTOPARENTSITE]$ ls -Z MYSITE/media/
drw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tmp
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 work_directory
```

### EDIT 2 - Complete log DEBUG

```
SyntaxError at /importData/upload
invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://IPSERVER/importData/upload
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)
Exception Location: /PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in Connect, line 80
Python Executable:  /PATHTOMYENV/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['PATHTOMYSITE',
 '/usr/lib64/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/PATHTOMYSITE',
 '/',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/odf',
 '/']
Server time:    jeu, 11 Oct 2018 15:03:11 +0200
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in _get_session
            return self._session_cache ...
▶ Local vars
During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
            if test_func(request.user): ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in <lambda>
        lambda u: u.is_authenticated, ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in inner
            self._setup() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in _setup
        self._wrapped = self._setupfunc() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in <lambda>
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request)) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py in get_user
        request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in get_user
        user_id = _get_user_session_key(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY]) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in __getitem__
        return self._session[key] ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py in _get_session
                self._session_cache = self.load() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py in load
                expire_date__gt=timezone.now() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get
        num = len(clone) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__
        self._fetch_all() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all
            self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
            sql, params = self.as_sql() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in as_sql
                where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", []) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in compile
            sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py in as_sql
                sql, params = compiler.compile(child) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in compile
            sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py in as_sql
        lhs_sql, params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py in process_lhs
        db_type = self.lhs.output_field.db_type(connection=connection) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in db_type
            return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in data_types
        if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision: ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py in supports_microsecond_precision
        return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in mysql_version
        with self.temporary_connection() as cursor: ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py in __enter__
            return next(self.gen) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in temporary_connection
        cursor = self.cursor() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in cursor
        return self._cursor() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in _cursor
        self.ensure_connection() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in ensure_connection
                self.connect() ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in get_new_connection
        return Database.connect(**conn_params) ...
▶ Local vars
/PATHTOMYENV/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in Connect
    from MySQLdb.connections import Connection ...
▶ Local vars
```

Comment: Does the user that runs the Django server has proper permissions on the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: What is `connections.py`? The error is from that file and nothing to do with settings. `invalid syntax (connections.py, line 36)`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i edited form yut question if i well understand you.

Comment: @DalinDad: wel it looks like only `apache` can write to the directory. What is the result of `import getpass; print(getpass.getuser())`? This should print the name of the user that is running the Django server.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i edited my post with the full log. i hope it can help

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it give `apache` (i put your code in settings.py)

Comment: arrghhh, the directory is not e`x`ecutable (you can not open id), add `chmod u+x` for the `tmp` directory.

Comment: So the directory needs 755 access.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's perfect... oO just to modify the mode of permission in my settings.py. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution found by `Willem Van Onsem` is to modify the mode of permission.

So in the `settings.py`, just change :

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

by :

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o755
```